# How to create multi-tenant functionality in laravel with 3 levels

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel project and I want it to be multi-tenant with 3 levels i.e.,

level 1: super admin- who will have all the permissions to access all the levels.

level 2: agency admin- who will have the permission to access all data created by his own agents.

level 3: agent- who can see only its own data.

Comment: Have you checked out [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization)? And what version of Laravel are you using, because you used two different versions in your tags

Comment: it is laravel 5.7.28

Answer (score 1):

two way you can solve this problem at laravel.
1. using role based access control.
   there have some package for laravel to manage RBAC check this one https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission
2. using laravel guard. laravel have multiple auth guard so you can manage it easily